# Api authorization basic concepts in detail

Tags: authentication

I am trying to write an application is rails. Which is more like a api application so that when a user gets redirected from his application into mine I would like to authorize him and start a session for his own. This session must be open till he leaves my application. How can I do this?

Comment: Please be sure to state the findings of your own research. Have you tried searching for answers on the Internet?

Answer (score 1):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OAuth

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenID

OAuth is an open standard to authorization. OAuth provides client applications a 'secure delegated access' to server resources on behalf of a resource owner. It specifies a process for resource owners to authorize third-party access to their server resources without sharing their credentials. Designed specifically to work with Hypertext Transfer Protocol (HTTP), OAuth essentially allows access tokens to be issued to third-party clients by an authorization server, with the approval of the resource owner, or end-user. The client then uses the access token to access the protected resources hosted by the resource server.[1] OAuth is commonly used as a way for web surfers to log into third party web sites using their Google, Facebook or Twitter accounts, without worrying about their access credentials being compromised.[2]

OAuth is a service that is complementary to, and therefore distinct from, OpenID. OAuth is also distinct from OATH, which is a reference architecture for authentication, not a standard.

Comment: Link-only answers aren't helpful because the links can go dead or the info can change. Please add the relevant info from the link so that this can become an answer.

Comment: it's a fairly broad topic; it's tempting to post the whole thing but the thesis points should do.

Comment: I know, but even an abstract can help the OP. Thanks for the edit.